# How to renew a US visa for a Dubai expat?

Tags: visas, usa, international-travel, legal, b1-b2-visas

I'm an Egyptian working in Dubai, UAE as an expat. I had a B1/B2 Us visa that expired 2 weeks ago. I travelled twice before to the US to attend technical conferences.
My US visa was originally issue 5 years ago in Cairo, Egypt.

Where should I apply for renewing the visa? Egypt or UAE?
I have no plans to travel to the US in the near future. Can I still renew the visa? or do I have to have a valid travel reason to renew it?
Is it a problem if I don't renew the visa right now and wait for a couple of years in the future for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, **if you're legally resident in a country, you can apply for the visa there**.  So you can apply in Dubai/UAE.

Since the B1/B2 visa is a "non-immigrant" visa, it cannot be renewed or extended, you need to apply for a new one.  To apply, you need to have a [specific tourism or business reason](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html).  So I would *not* recommended applying for it again until you have a reason to travel and some documentation to back it up.

Getting a 2nd visa is usually much easier than the 1st one, because you already have legitimate travel history.  There is no problem with a gap of a few years, particularly now with COVID, since a lot of frequent travellers are effectively grounded anyway.

Comment: It should also be noted that the US will let you apply for a visa regardless of your residency. I.e. many Russians fly to US consulates in the EU because lines are insane at the Moscow consulate.